# Load ReactNativeHost for Android with a bundle from a remote host

Tags: android, react-native

I've pre-compiled my react-native bundle and uploaded it to my server (fake url):

> http://my-bundle-server.com/index.android.bundle.js

For iOS I can just create a view using that location and it works just fine:

```
 jsCodeLocation = "http://my-bundle-server.com/index.android.bundle.js";
 RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc]
     initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation                                                      
     moduleName:@"MyCoolComponent"
     initialProperties:nil                                                  
     launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

With Android it's a different story, I couldn't find a way I can define that path for a remote bundle. I found the docs for the `ReactNativeHost` and tried to set the `getJSBundleFile` but it gives me `Could not load the file 'http://....js':

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactNativeHost.java

> Returns a custom path of the bundle file. This is used in cases the
>   bundle should be loaded from a custom path. By default, it is loaded
>   from Android assets, from a path specified by {@link
>   getBundleAssetName}. e.g.
>   "file://sdcard/myapp_cache/index.android.bundle"

It seems that it won't work with the remote locations. It worth mentioning that I'm creating my host in Application so I can reuse it in different fragments of my app.

How can I define pre-compiled bundle location to load for an Android app?

Answer (score 3):

The default implementation seems to use filesystem implementation:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/4466b6fa7ce5325cac3233a23b10ffcb4ff038a7/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java#L93

But it seems there is a possibility of exposing a bundler that could load  a remote url here (otherwise how would dev server url load bundle from localhost- rite?):

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/4466b6fa7ce5325cac3233a23b10ffcb4ff038a7/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/JSBundleLoader.java#L65

along with external facing api to set a custom bundleloader here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/4466b6fa7ce5325cac3233a23b10ffcb4ff038a7/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java#L112

P.S. I haven't tried any of above, but it seems workable.

Comment: What is sourceUrl etc? How would I use that? I'm a java noob here. Trying to use this as a workaround to getting my dev server running. Doesn't seem to connect but works fine at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up to Jay's answer,
here is a working implementation of a remote bundle

```
    ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setCurrentActivity(this).setJSBundleLoader(
                                JSBundleLoader.createCachedBundleFromNetworkLoader(
                                "index.android.bundle",
                                "http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=false&hot=false&minify=false"
                                )
                        )
```

I do however end up with this error :/ [TypeError:React.useEffect is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62570508/typeerrorreact-useeffect-is-not-a-function) but the bundler works and is triggered