# TypeError:React.useEffect is not a function

Tags: react-native

*I am getting this error but i dont know what i am getting this any help ?*

[image]

in LogBoxInspector.js,

i  dont know what this js doing, and there are some errors here.
[image]

Comment: Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Pass an arrow function.

Comment: @Imran i put picture of error place.

Comment: The question is clearly about React Native. I get the same issue after running `npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev true --entry-file index.js` on react-native 0.63.4 following this guide https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps

Answer (score 6):

import it like this

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
```

Comment: this solved my problem, from tutorial I used `import {useEffect} from 'react/cjs/react.development';` in a nextJS project, locally it was running fine but on a porduction server, it was causing errors. Using `import {useEffect} from 'react';` solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Please adhere to Stack Overflow guidelines while asking questions.

You need to import the hooks, you are using in your code.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

**Sample Code**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
  
  function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
  });
```